# my modal popup is not closing when browser back button is pressed in angular 5

Tags: angular

```
<ng-template #upload let-c="close" let-d="dismiss"   >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" >Upload File</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross 
          click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
</ng-template>
```

my modal popup is not closing when browser back button is pressed in angular 5
how can i close this popup when back button pressed..???

Answer (score 0):

Just for an suggestion ngOnDestroy() method call this close function.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   // apply close logic here.
}
```

Reference:-

https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Example:-
Html

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" #closeAddExpenseModal>&times;</button>
```

Typescript

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('closeAddExpenseModal') closeAddExpenseModal: ElementRef;

ngOnDestroy(){
 this.closeAddExpenseModal.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Comment: it shows..  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can listen `popstate` event of `window`.

If you modal is a component itself, you can use

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropogation();
    this.close(); // Or call what the dismiss method is
}
```

Or if you open modal in a component template:

If you modal is a component itself, you can use

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
    if(IS_MODAL_OPENED){ // check if modal is opened
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropogation();
       this.closeModal(); // Or call what the dismiss method is
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't really say without seeing how you open it. Can you update the question by adding how you open the modal? And also is your modal a separate component?

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.openPopup());
  }

  openPopup() {
    if (this.showFileUpload) {
      this.modalService.open(this.Modal).result.then((result) => {
        this.hideModal();
      }, (reason) => {
        this.Modal();
      });
    }
  }

Comment: I couldn't understand the code you provided in the comment. Can you add it and also contents of modal and modal service to the question?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer..

```html
openPopup() {
    if (this.showFileUpload) {
        this.mdl= this.modalService.open(this.uploadFileModal);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.mdl.close();
        }, 9000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can accomplish this on ngDestroy (https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)

 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.modalService.dismissAll("GridDestroyed");
}


This will close all the open modals on the browser back, 

Refrence : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngb-modal
```